# how can we add intent and utternces in luis through APIs in node js code

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Im trying to add intent and utterances through node js code, but i am not getting any endpoint , where we can set data intent and utterances in json format

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [Authoring REST API (v3 - Preview)](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-programmatic-apis-v3-0-preview/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f) or [Authoring REST API (v2)](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f).

You can add intents via [`models > Create Intent`](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-programmatic-apis-v3-0-preview/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c0c). You can add utterances via [`example utterances > Add label`](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c08).

Note, that in all of these `{endpoint}` in the URL refers to the endpoint for the APIs, one of:

- Australia East - australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- West Europe - westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
- West US - westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

...and [it's based off of your authoring region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions).

If you're not familiar with making API requests in Node, take a look at either [`Axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [`Node Fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) to make the API calls.

Comment: Thanks ,now i am able to do such things